# Is it possible to cast to templated class without type information?

Tags: c++

Let's assume that I have a templated class like this:

```
template<typename Fn>
struct S {
  S(Fn fn) : fn_(fn) {}

  const auto& fn() const {
    return fn_;
  }
  Fn fn_;
}
```

There are times that you need to pass your object as `void*`, so if I have a pointer like this:

```
void* ptr = new S{[]() { std::cout << "hi!\n";}};
```

everything is just fine. But the problem is that if I try to cast `ptr` back to my class to have access to `fn()` method, I will need type information. So following code will **not** compile:

```
auto s = static_cast<S*>(ptr);
```

Now my question is that if there is a pattern or method to carry type information alongside data to make this casting possible or not? Using anything approach/pattern that returns correct the instance is fine. Use cases of this problem is when you are working with a libraries that passes context between methods as `void*`. If you want to use a templated class as that context, this problem happens.

Any idea?

Comment: `std::function` does that. Its called type erasure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core problem here is that you want to use a lambda as a type's template parameter, then you want to be able to cast it to/from a `void*`. The type of a lambda is unknown, generated by the compiler. And even if it were known, you would be unable to type it.

So instead, you need to remove the type from `S` and shove it into `S`'s constructor:

```
struct S {
  template<typename Func>
  S(Func &&fn) : fn_(std::forward<Func>(fn)) {}

  auto const& fn() const {
    return fn_;
  }

  std::function<void()> fn_;
}
```

You need to internally erase the type so that code trying to undo the erasure has a known type to work with.

Comment: Yea, this approach is possible only in case as, as you mentioned, you know the type in the end or be able to embed it in another known type. My problem is exactly that I don't know the type (since I didn't want to link my code to specific type) and cannot find a way to embed it in another type (this case is possible with std::function, but you can easily find a case which is not). I thought maybe there is a way to save type in a base class and use it, but it seems it is not the case.

Comment: @Afshin: You can use template *derived* classes of a base class; this is a common way to implement type erasure. But you don't reconstitute the original type; you simply put `virtual` functions in the base class that the derived template classes implement, and you call those `virtual` functions.

Comment: Yea, the problem is that you cannot have `auto` as return type of `virtual` method in base. Imagine that you want a virtual getter method in base class to return templated member variable in derived class, something like this: `virtual auto get_x() const = 0;` which is incorrect. If you know types, you can use something like `virtual std::string get_x() const = 0;` in the base class, so we still need to know type and it will not completely generic.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a few options:

1. Inherit every class from a base class and use dynamic polymorphism.
2. Use std::function
3. Use std::variant
4. Use std::any

Each of these methods is different in cost and features but will do what you wanted.

Comment: In reality, I knew all these methods and non of them worked for me. what I needed was type easure concept which was mentioned in the comment. In everything that you suggested, I need to know type in the end.

Comment: @Afshin: Type erasure can't really work without, at some point, knowing the actual type in question. Or at least, you cannot unerase it without knowing the type. If you need to know a specific typename, you can't use a lambda.